# Razor Pages doesn't use it's layout

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I've created a LayoutAdmin.cshtml which is located in ~/Pages/Shared folder. It's referenced in the Index.cshtml located in ~/Pages/Admin like this:

```
@page
@{ 
    Layout = "_LayoutAdmin";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Admin Home";
}
```

but when I go to that page, it uses the default layout as in any other page. What is the cause of this? Is there a default layout specified somewhere in the code that overwrites my specified layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

`~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <h1>This is Admin layout </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`~/Pages/Admin/Index`

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_LayoutAdmin";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Admin Home";
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you did the exact same thing but mine doesn't work. It only renders what I've put into the "Index", not what I've specified in the layout.

Comment: You can create a new project to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've fixed the issue.
I've deleted the _Layout.cshtml page and made a new one as an empty razor page with the same content.

Comment: I think there is another way to set the default Layout to null in your `_ViewStart.`

Comment: I'm using the _ViewStart but the _Layout file itself didn't work before changing it to a razor page with the same code.